# Query string in url and conditions

Tags: php, url, linked-list, query-string

please help me with  with the following listing. I do not know where I'm making a mistake.

My table:

```
year | distributor | item | nameautor
1994 | Nike | Book | John
1994 | Nike | Book | Peter
1994 | Nike | DVD | Jessie
1994 | Nike | DVD | Marc
1995 | O2 | Book | Heck
1995 | O2 | Book | Lars
etc.
```

A complete link list will appear on the page *index.php*

Example:

```
1994 Nike
1995 O2
```

Once the link (1994 Nike) is clicked, it will appear:

```
1994 Nike Book
1994 Nike DVD
```

And the last step is when you click on - 1994 Nike Book:

```
1994 Nike Book John
1994 Nike Book Peter
```

I have the following codes, and I do not know how to link them together.

**1. step**

```
<?php
$query="(SELECT DISTINCT year, distributor FROM table)";
$back=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
while (list($year,$distributor) = mysql_fetch_row($back)){
    echo ("<a href=\"index.php?$year&$distributor\"><b></b>$year - $distributor</a></br>");
    }
?>
```

**2. step**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $year = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $distributor = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $namechoose = str_replace(array('%20', '&'), ' ' , $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $query="(select distinct year, distributor, item FROM table WHERE CONCAT(year, ' ', distributor)='$namechoose')";
    $back=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    echo ("<h3><center>you choose --- $namechoose ---</center></h3>");
    while (list($year,$distributor,$item) = mysql_fetch_row($back)){
        echo ("<a href=\"index.php?$year&$distributor&$item\"><b></b>$year - $distributor - $item</a></br>");   
        } 
} 
?>
```

**The last step**

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $year = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $distributor = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $item = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $detailedtable = str_replace(array('%20', '&'), ' ' , $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    $query="(select distinct year, distributor, item, nameautor FROM table WHERE CONCAT(year, ' ', distributor, ' ', item)='$detailedtable')";
        $back=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    echo TABLE LISTING;
}
?>
```

I have tried this structure, but it does not work as I wish.

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) && !empty($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    if (!isset($_GET['item'])) {
            $year = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $distributor = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $namechoose = str_replace(array('%20', '&'), ' ' , $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
            $query="(select distinct year, distributor, item FROM table WHERE CONCAT(year, ' ', distributor)='$namechoose')";
            $back=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
            echo ("<h3><center>you choose --- $namechoose ---</center></h3>");
            while (list($year,$distributor,$item) = mysql_fetch_row($back)){
                echo ("<a href=\"index.php?$year&$distributor&$item\"><b></b>$year - $distributor - $item</a></br>");   
                } 
     } else {
            $year = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $distributor = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $item = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
            $detailedtable = str_replace(array('%20', '&'), ' ' , $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
            $query="(select distinct year, distributor, item, nameautor FROM table WHERE CONCAT(year, ' ', distributor, ' ', item)='$detailedtable')";
               $back=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
            echo TABLE LISTING;
         } 
    }
else {
    $query="(SELECT DISTINCT year, distributor FROM table)";
    $back=mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while (list($year,$distributor) = mysql_fetch_row($back)){
        echo ("<a href=\"index.php?$year&$distributor\"><b></b>$year - $distributor</a></br>");
        }
}
?>
```

Is it a bad structure?

Thank you for your comments.

Comment: *"Is it a bad structure?"* - Maybe or maybe not, but the api you're using is.

Comment: ... or maybe that's really what the question is about? Your URL should be `<a href=\"index.php?year=$year&distrubtor=$distributor\">` then you access them via `$_GET`. The year being in `$_GET['year']`.

Comment: where is `codeigniter` used here ?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help.

I have modified the code using

```
echo ("<a href=\"index.php?year=$year&distributor=$distributor&item=$item\"><b></b>$year - $distributor - $item</a></br>");
```

And now it works as it should.